# jTextPane color with some exception in chat

Tags: java, swing, styles, chat, jtextpane

I am using jTextPane to use sender and receiver chat color. All works fine but `javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument@123456`with every chat message.

---

here Jhon is revceiver and peter is sender

[image]

---

here peter is revceiver and Jhon is sender

[image]

may be I m doing some mistake in code.

### Here is the code for Sender

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss\n\t   dd/MM/yyyy ");
        Date date = new Date();

        StyledDocument doc = GUI.jTextPane1.getStyledDocument();
        Style style = GUI.jTextPane1.addStyle("a style", null);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.red);

    try { 

        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\t  " + "You" + " : " + GUI.getSendMessage() +("\n \t   "+dateFormat.format(date)) ,style); 
        GUI.appendReceivedMessages(""+doc);
        }
    catch (BadLocationException e){}
```

### Here is the code for Receiver

```
DateFormat dateFormate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss\ndd/MM/yyyy ");
            Date datee = new Date();
            StyledDocument doc1 = GUI.jTextPane1.getStyledDocument();
            Style styler = GUI.jTextPane1.addStyle("a style", null);

             StyleConstants.setForeground(styler, Color.blue);

            try { doc1.insertString(doc1.getLength(),"recevier" ,styler); 
                GUI.appendReceivedMessages(fromHeader.getAddress().getDisplayName() + " : "
                    + new String(request.getRawContent()) +("\n"+dateFormate.format(datee)));                
            }
            catch (BadLocationException e){}
```

### here is Main GUI where I get these

```
public void appendReceivedMessages(String s) {
            try {
  Document doce = jTextPane1.getDocument();
  doce.insertString(doce.getLength(), s+"\n", null);
   } catch(BadLocationException exc) {

  }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is so obvious - not sure if qualifies for an answer. Anyway

Why are you doing `GUI.appendReceivedMessages(""+doc);` ? that is causing the `doc` object's default `toString` to appear. Hope that helps

**EDIT:**

> so what can I do here

I guess you can do it like this :
Note that `StyledDocument`'s `insertString` API updates the view. Meaning it provides you the output you need on `JTextPane` so:

`doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\t  " + "You" + " : " + GUI.getSendMessage() +("\n \t   "+dateFormat.format(date)) ,style);`

Is sufficient to bring the output on to the text pane. Remove the call to `GUI.appendReceivedMessages(""+doc);`

I believe your aim is to display the message text on the text pane component - `jTextPane1`.  you just need to  update property of `jTextPane1` for that. You do not need to update anything else. If you need to send the text data around, just get the text from that object and pass it around to methods that expects the value : example :

```
String text = jTextPane1.getDocument()
                .getText(0, jTextPane1.getDocument()
                             .getLength());

aMethodThatExpectsAString(text);
```

Comment: so what I can do here... I am beginner so I try my best all my ideas and then I post this here ..

Comment: if I remove `GUI.appendReceivedMessages(""+doc);` then how the data send to the GUI. @ring bearer

Comment: can u help on this @MaVRoSCy

Comment: you see the question that there is one sender  and receiver and both text chats merge/append into one `jTextPane` @ring bearer